# PHP Object access with class constant

Tags: php, class-constants

Is it possible in PHP to access a member of an object where the name of the member is specified by a class constant?

Consider this example:

```
class X{
    const foo = "abc";
}

class Y{
    public $abc;
}

$y = new Y();

$y->X::foo = 23; //This does not work
```

The parser doesn't accept the last line but this is what I want. I want to access the field with the name stored in the class constant `X::foo`. Is there a syntax to achieve that?

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch as variable variables have been part of PHP since god knows how long they're supported just fine by major IDEs like PhpStorm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), either via a temp or directly:

```
$name = X::foo;          // Via temp var
$y->$name = 23;          // Access the member by the string's content
var_dump($y->{X::foo});  // Dumps 23
```

[Working sample here](https://eval.in/92321).

Answer (score 3):

You should write your code like this

```
$y->{X::foo} = 23;
```

Hope it helps